# Creating a new package close an environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages

So I am trying to create a new package for Latex. Currently I have one function like this:

```
\def\timeline#1#2#3{%
   % draw the timeline
}%
```

In this function I open the tikz environment with `\begin{tikzpicture}`. I also have a function which draws a single event into this environment, which can be called multiple times.

Now I am not sure how to close the tikz environment after all events have been added. Can somebody explain this to me?

Currently I have the following code in the sty file:

```
\newenvironment{cvtimeline}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
}{%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
% Functions
\def\timeline#1#2#3{%
   % draw the timeline
}%

\def\work#1#2#3#4#5{%
   % add an work event and draw
}%
\def\school#1#2#3#4#5{%
   % add an school event and draw
}%
```

This can be used in a `tex` file as follows:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{cvtimeline}
        \timeline{2009}{2017}{\textwidth}
        \work{2009}{8}{2013}{8}{Hello}
        \work{2013}{10}{2014}{8}{World}
    \end{cvtimeline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to create a LaTeX package, you should use LaTeX syntax.

Comment: @Johannes_B and this means?

Comment: As far as I understood, you want to create a command, which opens an environment and another command which closes the environment? I think, what @Johannes_B refers to is `\newcommmand` instead of `\def`. I also often use `def`, because I'm a lazy prick.

Comment: You can use `\newenvironment` instead of `\def` (or `\newcommand`) to define your timeline: `\newenvironment{timeline}[3]{... code to open your environment...}{... code to close you envrionment...}`

Comment: In my opinion the command `\timeline` is defined according to LaTeX syntax. It is defined using `\def` which is TeX, but considering that the majority of packages uses this convention I don't see a major problem, as long as you are sure that the command is not earlier defined. But it could also be that @Johannes_B encourage you to use LaTeX `\newenvironment` for your environment. That will make the closing much easier.

Comment: So if I create a new environment with `\newenvironment` the I can draw the timeline. But how do I define the command to create a new event? Do I do this with `def` or what is the equivalent in LaTeX syntax? Because I found a lot of packages that use `def`, so I am sorry if this is wrong.

Comment: Pascal, i think there are some packages already around to draw timelines. Are you sure you want to add one on top of that?

Comment: @Johannes_B Yeah, I know there are some packages around. I also looked into them. But they do not do what I want. I created a LaTex file which does what I want. Now I just want to pack it into a sty file for easier usage.

Comment: It is hard to suggest syntax when you have shown no example of any relevant code or intended use but it sounds like you should be defining an environment. If `\timeline` is defined as above and `\endtimeline` is defined to be `\end{tikzpicture}` and whatever else is needed the use would be `\begin{timeline}{a}{b}{c}.... \end{timeline}`

Comment: I added some more code, which perhaps explains my intention better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure your code as

document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mytimeline}

\begin{document}

    \begin{cvtimeline}{2009}{2017}{\textwidth}
        \work{2009}{8}{2013}{8}{Hello}
        \work{2013}{10}{2014}{8}{World}
    \end{cvtimeline}

\end{document}
```

package `mytimeline.sty`

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newenvironment{cvtimeline}[3]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
    % the code that you had in \timeline
}{%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
% Functions
%\def\timeline#1#2#3{%
%   % draw the timeline
%}%

\def\work#1#2#3#4#5{%
   % add an work event and draw
}%
\def\school#1#2#3#4#5{%
   % add an school event and draw
}%
```